# Java Multithreading Printing Odd and Even Number

Tags: java, multithreading

i have started learning Threading in java. I have wrriten a code to print odd and even number in sequence order. But the ouput i am getting is twice.
Below is my code.

ThreadBasic1.java:

```
public class ThreadBasic1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


       Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadImplementation1());
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadImplementation1());

       t1.start();
       t2.start();

    }
}
```

ThreadImplementation1.java:

```
public class ThreadImplementation1 implements Runnable {

    boolean isOdd= false;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread started :: Thread name :: " + Thread.currentThread());
        try {
           for(int i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
               if(i %2 ==0) {
                   printEven(i);
               }
               else {
                   printOdd(i);
               }
           }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }





    synchronized void printEven(int number)throws InterruptedException  {
        while(!isOdd){
            try {

                wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even:"+number);
        isOdd = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
    synchronized void printOdd(int number) throws InterruptedException {

        while (isOdd) {

            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Odd :"+number);

        isOdd = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
thread started :: Thread name :: Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Odd :1
Even:2
Odd :3
Even:4
Odd :5
Even:6
Odd :7
Even:8
Odd :9
thread started :: Thread name :: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Odd :1
Even:2
Odd :3
Even:4
Odd :5
Even:6
Odd :7
Even:8
Odd :9
```

Comment: Unrelated: you want us to spend our time to help you with your problem.So you please spend the time to properly format your input.

Comment: because  you have 2 threads started, thats why...

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is simple: you have two threads that do exactly the same: print the numbers from 1 to 9.

Typically, such exercises require you to have slightly different code for each thread. One thread **only** prints odd numbers, the *other* thread prints the even ones. Then both threads need to go in lock step, in order to achieve proper 1 2 3 4 output. Or you have "one" thread implementation, but you somehow enable to *configure* the behavior of that thread.

Thus the answer here is to step back and re-think your whole approach. There is no point in having two threads doing the **same**. That just means that you *repeat* some behavior. Instead, figure how to *align* **two** different behaviors.

Of course, I will not give you the code for that: the whole point of the exercise is that you turn these ideas into code.

Comment: There's also no point in having the threads run in lock step.

Comment: @nicomp Depends on the exact requirement. When you want 1 2 3 4 5 show up in the right order, you *somehow* have to account for that. Very much depends on what needs to be done, and then *how* it is done.

Comment: then you don't need threads. Two threads in lockstep accomplishes the same things as one thread.

Comment: True. But the point is not to do that because it is the only technical solution. You do such things to learn how to them.

Comment: Definitely. And we should do them so some productive end, even a trivial productive end.

Answer (score -1):

You should ideally run just 1 thread which does the toggle job b/w even and odd for you.

```
package com.samples;

public class ThreadBasic1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadImplementation1());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadImplementation1());

    t1.start();
    //t2.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Which of course, is technically correct, but well, if you go with that, you dont need threads at all. You would just call that looping method right  in the main method. There is no point in having *one* thread when working on a *multi thread* exercise.

Comment: so, can someone modify my code to get desired result.

Comment: i am learning multithreading and i think this is the basic to start with. and help by code will be appriciated